# Как читать псевдокод в описании к SIMD-инструкциям intel

Tags: c++, c, simd

Не смог полностью понять, как же читать псевдокод с описания SIMD-инструкций с сайта Intel.
Ну для примера на функции _mm_cvtepu8_epi32: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_cvtepu8_epi32&ig_expand=1941,657,1826,6382,1826,6124,1941

```
__m128i _mm_cvtepu8_epi32 (__m128i a)

Description
Zero extend packed unsigned 8-bit integers in a to packed 32-bit integers, and store the results in dst.

Operation:

FOR j := 0 to 3
    i := 32*j
    k := 8*j
    dst[i+31:i] := ZeroExtend32(a[k+7:k])
ENDFOR
```

Для начала я приведу результат работы этой "функции":

```
#include <iostream>

#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main()
{

     __m128i my_add_m128i_SET_value =  _mm_set_epi8(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1);

     __m128i my_temp_result = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(my_add_m128i_SET_value );
}
```

Результат по байтово в  битах будет такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понял, то вот такая запись [i+31:i] - означат, что к примеру при i=0, означает от (0+31) до 0. Если так, ну вот я сделал такую табличку c посчитанными значениями j,i,k:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, как я понял запись  dst[i+31:i] - означает, что для данного диапазона битов в результативном векторе __m128i - это диапазон будет равен ZeroExtend32[...] и вот тут все, тут я уже начинаю не понимать.

Из таблички видно, что для j=xxx:

dst[31:0]   = ZeroExtend32[7:0] - **то есть ZeroExtend32 берет биты с 0 по 7 Входного вектора копирует их в Выходной вектор, в диапазон 31:0 и все остальное в диапазоне [31:0] - заменяет нулями.**

dst[63:32]  = ZeroExtend32[263:256] - **А вот тут что получается ?? Что это за значения такие 263:256** ??

dst[95:64]  = ZeroExtend32[519:512]

dst[127:96] = ZeroExtend32[775:768]

Comment: Что-то я не понял.... Где Вы взяли такие значения ```k``` ?

Comment: @Юрий Козлов, из псевдокода: k := 8*j.

Comment: Именно.... Тогда ```k = 0, 8, 16 ,24``` Вы перепутали  ```i``` и ```j```

Comment: @Optimus1 И какие значения для j будут использованы? Вы невнимательно посмотрели

Comment: @Юрий Козлов, да ёжкин кот, меня эта невнимательность, когда нибудь подведет конкретно. В описании k := 8*j, а я увидел k := 8*i. :(